# How to make it so that matplotlib graph titles are included in window when running .py file in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, matplotlib, command-line, anaconda

```
 import numpy as np
 from matplotlib_venn import venn2, venn2_circles, venn2_unweighted
 from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

 plt.title(print("Shared",Signature_1, 'and',Signature_2, 'and',Signature_3))
 venn3(subsets = (len(NameA), len(NameB), len(shared_A_B), len(NameC), len(shared_A_C), 
 len(shared_C_B), len(shared_A_B_C)), set_labels = (Signature_1, Signature_2, Signature_3), alpha = 0.5)
 plt.show()
```

This code produces titles for plots in jupyter notebook only. When I run the .py script in Anaconda prompt only the plot is visible. How would I go about getting the titles to appear in the plot window? I realized because these are formatted to take variables [plt.title(print("title",variable,etc.)] that they do not work in command line. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to move the title inside the plot window. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is correct or alternativity in the title of the pop up window

Comment: Okay. Does my answer help then?

Comment: print("Shared",Signature_1, 'and',Signature_2, 'and',Signature_3), because this is a print function title with variables it does not work in command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.format` method to include a variable into the print/title.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,10)
y = x**2

plt.plot(x,y)
variable ='IamVar'
Signature_1='one'
Signature_2='two'
Signature_3='three'

# \n stands for newline

plt.suptitle("Moving title - {} and {},{} \n set=({},{})".format(Signature_1,Signature_2,Signature_3,len(x),len(y))     
             ,size=8,x=0.3, y=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you can simply do `plt.title("Shared, {} and, {}, and {}".format(Signature_1,Signature_1,Signature_3)`. Let me know if it works for you. I will update the answer for your title.

Comment: What would the syntax look like for multiple variables, for example:   plt.title(print("Shared",Signature_1, 'and',Signature_2, 'and',Signature_3))

Comment: I have updated the answer as well. Glad I could help.